# Make file warning, overriding commands for target

Tags: makefile, warnings

As part of the makefile i'd like to produce either a debug or release version of the target.

**Functionally, everything is working**, however, i am getting warnings when running make

```
 12 SRC := $(shell echo src/*.cpp)
 13 SRC += $(shell echo $(TEST_ROOT)/*.cpp)
 14 
 15 D_OBJECTS = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)       # same objects will need to be built differently
 16 R_OBJECTS = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)       # same objects will need to be built differently

 22 all: $(TARGET)
 23 
 25 $(TARGET): $(D_OBJECTS)
 26   $(CC) $(D_OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET)
 27 
 28 $(D_OBJECTS) : %.o: %.cpp                     # ----- run with debug flags 
 29   $(CC) $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
 30 
 31 release: $(R_OBJECTS)
 32   $(CC) $(R_OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET)
 33 
 34 $(R_OBJECTS) : %.o: %.cpp                     # ----- run with release flags
 35   $(CC) $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(RELEASE_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

When i `make` i get debug version, when i `make release` i get release version.

But i also get warnings:

```
Makefile:35: warning: overriding commands for target `src/Timer.o'
Makefile:29: warning: ignoring old commands for target `src/Timer.o'
Makefile:35: warning: overriding commands for target `test/TimerTest.o'
Makefile:29: warning: ignoring old commands for target `test/TimerTest.o'
```

With this 2 questions:

1. Any way to ignore the warnings
2. Am i doing things right? What changes are needed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of the most common ways for doing this is to put the release objects and the debug objects in separate subdirectories. That way you don't get redefinitions for the rules for an object, since they will have different names. Something like this:

```
D_OBJECTS=$(SRC:%.cpp=debug/%.o)
R_OBJECTS=$(SRC:%.cpp=release/%.o)

RTARGET = a.out
DTARGET = a.out.debug

all : dirs $(RTARGET)

debug : dirs $(DTARGET)

dirs :
    @mkdir -p debug release

debug/%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(DEBUG_CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

release/%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(RELEASE_CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(DTARGET) : $(D_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(DEBUG_CFLAGS) -o $@ $(D_OBJECTS)

$(RTARGET) : $(R_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(RELEASE_CFLAGS) -o $@ $(R_OBJECTS)
```

Comment: Do you know how to do that in netbeans which auto generates Makefile?

Comment: or create a library if you have same code for multiple binaries

Answer (score 29):

Like the OP (James Leonard), I would like to suppress or avoid warnings about overriding `Makefile` targets.  However, my situation and goals are different.

I want `Makefile` to `include base.mk`, and I want `Makefile` to be able to override targets from `base.mk` without any warning messages.  I am using GNU Make.

The GNU Make documentation describes one way of doing this:

Create `Makefile` as follows:

```
foo:
        echo 'bar' > foo

%: force
        @$(MAKE) -f base.mk $@
force: ;
```

Source:  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding-Makefiles.html

The above method has the (potentially serious) disadvantage that it will invoke a separate instance of `$(MAKE)`, meaning that (some or all?) variables may (will?) not be shared between the parent and child invocations of make.

Happily, I found a better solution, as outlined below:

Create `base.mk` as follows:

```
foo-default:
        echo  'foo-default'

bar-default:
        echo  'bar-default'

%:  %-default
        @  true
```

Create `Makefile` as follows:

```
include  base.mk

foo:
        echo  'foo  Makefile'
```

Example output:

```
$ make foo
echo  'foo  Makefile'
foo  Makefile

$ make bar
echo  'bar-default'
bar-default
```

Note that you need to be able to control the names of the targets in `base.mk` so that you can name them `<target>-default`.  In other words, you cannot use this approach to extend arbitrary base makefiles.  However, if you control both `base.mk` and `Makefile`, this approach will allow you to create one `base.mk` and then many customizations of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works perfect for my case

Comment: Love this! Using it here now: https://github.com/aclark4life/universal-project-makefile

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried if I could use this technique with variables like https://pastebin.com/yPkV9DXy . But no luck.(works, but with warnings) (gmake 4.2.1). I can expand all commands with -default, but I want to keep it DRY. if anyone can solve this, please add comments here...

Comment: @benok - Have you tried GNU make's `foreach` function?  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html

Comment: @mpb, Thanks for your comment. I want to check & try `foreach` sometime soon.

Comment: It worked for me if declare xxx-default targets in base.mk as .PHONY

Comment: It works but the targets without `-default`, e.g. `bar`, do not show in bash completion unless they are overridden.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid including the same file many times, you can use a C-style header 'directive':

```
ifeq ($(_MY_MAKEFILE_),)
_MY_MAKEFILE_ := defined

...

endif
```

- `ifeq` here is just saying "is the value empty"
- it's possible something similar can be done with `ifndef` but I got this working first
- the value "defined" is just anything that isn't blank

Comment: IMO that's absolutely the best method.

Answer (score -8):

I complied my own make and commented out section where those warning are printed. Works like a charm.  make v4.2, read.c,  around line 2114

Comment: You are not contributing to the answer by suggesting to comment out the code.