# I can't get Makefile ifeq syntax to work (checking age of a file)

Tags: makefile

I am attempting to use [an inheritance hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49804748/751) (which is already working) along with checking a file date to create a sort of reusable, auto-updating base makefile from which multiple projects can inherit; and which will update the parent Makefile using a `git pull`, but (and this is where I'm stuck) I only want it to try the `git pull` once per day, so that it doesn't add up to a lot of wasted time waiting on a git pull when the chance of updates being available is almost nothing.

The basic idea is this:

```
baseMakefilePath=../../baseMakefile

do_some_work: .check-for-update
    @echo "working..."

.check-for-update:
    # is the file > 24 hours old?
    ifeq ( $(find . -mtime +24h -name '.check-makefile-update'), ./.check-makefile-update )
        @make .update
    else
        # if the file doesn't exist at all yet, pull the update
        ifeq ( $(find . -name '.check-makefile-update'), '' )
            @make .update
        else
            @echo "last update was recent, not updating..."
        endif
    endif

.update:
    cd $(baseMakefilePath) && git pull
    touch .check-makefile-update
```

My theory is that by updating the modified timestamp on the `.check-makefile-update` file using `touch` it should only run the git pull once per day.

However, I can't even get a dirt simple `ifeq()` conditional to work:

```
test:
    ifeq (a, a)
        @echo "a basic test works"
    else
        @echo "idunno"
    endif
```

With this basic Makefile (note: this is the ONLY contents of the Makefile when I test it), I get this error:

```
$ make test
ifeq (a, a)
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `a,'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifeq (a, a)'
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

I get the same result if I try to run the first Makefile:

```
$ make do_some_work
# is the file > 24 hours old?
ifeq ( , ./.check-makefile-update )
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `,'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifeq ( , ./.check-makefile-update )'
make: *** [.check-for-update] Error 2
```

I think the stripped down example shows that there's something funky going on (or my understanding of ifeq is fundamentally flawed) but for what it's worth, I also tried quoting various combinations of the ifeq arguments, with both single and double quotes.

I'm out of ideas, but I feel like I'm *sooo close* to a working solution! What am I doing wrong?

If it matters, I'm on OSX 10.14.5, and my primary shell is `zsh`. It is not an *absolute requirement* but would be good if the solution can also run on modern versions of Windows (with WSL), too.

Comment: For C and C++ code consider using [ccache](https://ccache.dev/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of `ifeq` is fundamentally flawed :)

A makefile is a combination of two different syntaxes: the makefile itself is written in make syntax, and the recipes are written in shell syntax.

Those two syntaxes are not in any way compatible: you can't use make syntax when you are writing recipes and you can't use shell syntax when you are writing makefiles.

How do you know which is which?  The simplest way to think about it is that if the first character on your line is indented with a TAB character, it's shell syntax and if it's not, it's make syntax.  The reality is more subtle but that rule is always true.

I'm sure you can now see what's wrong with your makefile AND also why you get the errors you do:

```
test:
    ifeq (a, a)
        @echo "a basic test works"
    else
        @echo "idunno"
    endif
```

you are trying to pass make syntax to the shell.

Comment: Your answer has a more complete explanation of the problem so I want to select it as the accepted answer, but you haven't actually provided the answer. ;) Would you mind editing that in first?

Comment: Well, the actual answer depends on what you want to compare.  If what you want to compare are _MAKE_ things, like make variables etc. that don't depend on the rule being run (e.g., are not using automatic variables like `$@` or `$<`), then the answer is to remove the TABs.  If what you want to compare IS depending on the rule being run, then you have to convert the make conditional into a shell conditional and keep the TABs.  So, there's no one right answer, it depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that there are *Make* conditionals, and *shell* conditionals.

Here:

```
test:
    ifeq (a, a)
        @echo "a basic test works"
    else
        @echo "idunno"
    endif
```

I assume you're trying to use a Make conditional, but if those whitespace margins are TABs, then you're inadvertantly telling Make that those lines are shell commands which it should pass to the shell as they are. The shell tries to interpret `ifeq (a, a)` and complains of a syntax error.

Remove some of the TABs (leaving the ones in front of the actual shell commands):

```
test:
ifeq (a, a)
    @echo "a basic test works"
else
    @echo "idunno"
endif
```

and it works.