# Run different code in Makefile depending on the age of a file

Tags: makefile

I am attempting to create an auto-update mechanism for shared, inherited base-makefile code, and I only want it to check for updates once per day. Having fixed [my misunderstanding of how `ifeq` works in Makefiles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66771818/751), I think the last thing I need to figure out is why the values I'm comparing don't behave as expected.

I'm trying to use the last modified timestamp on a file `.makefile-update-ts` to indicate the last time an update was run, and checking that by using `find . -mtime +24h -name '.makefile-update-ts'` to indicate whether it's old enough yet. I'm not getting any syntax errors, and the values I get back from my various `find` commands seem to be correct, so I don't understand why, but my logic isn't working...

So let's start at the most basic and work our way up:

Starting with a pretty vanilla Makefile:

```
work:
ifeq (a,a)
    @echo "A"
else
    @echo "not A"
endif
```

```
$ make work
A
```

✅ works as expected

If I then graduate to use a variable to store the "a" value:

```
thing=a
compare=a

work:
ifeq ($(thing),$(compare))
    @echo "A"
else
    @echo "not A"
endif
```

```
$ make work
A
```

✅ works as expected

So let's switch to using `find` to get some indications of whether the file exists, and whether it's >= 24h old.

```
ts-filename=.makefile-update-ts
exists=`find . -name '$(ts-filename)'`
old=`find . -mtime +24h -name '$(ts-filename)'`
match=./$(ts-filename)

work:
    @echo "$(match) (match)"
    @echo "$(exists) (exists)"
    @echo "$(old) (old)"
```

```
$touch .makefile-update-ts
$make work
./.makefile-update-ts (match)
./.makefile-update-ts (exists)
 (old)
```

✅ Seems like the `find` commands are getting the values I want and I'm able to echo them out. Since I just created the file, the "old" search finds nothing, which is expected.

Time to graduate to the final script... or so I thought. In the makefile below I've added some extra `echo`s to illustrate the state of things at the time of compare, which when taken alongside the output of the various commands that get executed, doesn't make sense.

```
ts-filename=.makefile-update-ts
exists=`find . -name '$(ts-filename)'`
old=`find . -mtime +24h -name '$(ts-filename)'`
match=./$(ts-filename)

work: .check-for-update
    @echo "working..."

.check-for-update:
# is the file > 24 hours old?
ifeq ($(old),$(match))
    @echo checking for Makefile updates...
    @make .update
else
    @echo $(match) - "match"
    @echo $(old) - "old"
# if the file doesn't exist at all yet, pull the update
ifeq ($(exists),$(match))
    @echo "last update was recent, not updating..."
else
    @echo $(exists) - "exists"
    @echo Getting base Makefile...
    @make .update
endif
endif

.update:
    touch $(ts-filename)
```

```
$ make work
./.makefile-update-ts - match
- old
./.makefile-update-ts - exists
Getting base Makefile...
touch .makefile-update-ts
working...
```

❌ Why, if the file exists, and it's *not* "old" (`$(old)` is empty), does it print "Getting base Makefile..."??? I would expect it to instead print, "last update was recent, not updating..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is back to the original misunderstanding.  Makefiles are not shell scripts.  Consider this:

```
exists=`find . -name '$(ts-filename)'`
old=`find . -mtime +24h -name '$(ts-filename)'`
```

backticks are a *shell* feature.  Make doesn't know anything about them.  You've here declared two variables that contain the *literal strings* containing backticks and the commands, not, as in the shell, the *output* of running those commands.

So for this:

```
ifeq ($(old),$(match))
```

it expands to compare the *literal strings*:

```
ifeq (`find . -mtime +24h -name '$(ts-filename)'`,./.makefile-update-ts)
```

Obviously those strings are not equal.

If you want to run a shell script and assign its output to a make variable, you have to use make's [`shell` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html), like this:

```
exists := $(shell find . -name '$(ts-filename)')
old := $(shell find . -mtime +24h -name '$(ts-filename)')
```

A few points here:

I use `:=` instead of `=` to make it a bit more efficient.

I strongly recommend that you use whitespace around your assignment operators when dealing with *make* variables, rather than run them all together with no whitespace as you would have to with *shell* variables.  Maybe this cognitive dissonance will help reinforce the difference.  Plus, it's just better.

Oh, you may ask, why does your third example work?  Simple, it's because you are passing the *literal strings* to the *shell* and the *shell* is doing the expansion for you.  You can easily see this, if you remove the `@` prefixes on your shell script lines.  Another tip is, **NEVER** add `@` to any makefile recipe until you are 100% sure it's working perfectly (and, even then you might consider not doing it).

If you remove them you'll see:

```
work:
        echo "$(old) (old)"
```

This will print:

```
echo "`find . -mtime +24h -name '$(ts-filename)'` `find . -mtime +24h -name '$(ts-filename)'`"
./.makefile-update-ts ./.makefile-update-ts
```

Instead of what you'd expect IF the make variable contained the already-expanded content, which would be:

```
echo "./.makefile-update-ts ./.makefile-update-ts"
./.makefile-update-ts ./.makefile-update-ts
```

Another tip is, when you are trying to use *MAKE* variables from within a shell script you should always (unless the value might contain single quotes) single quotes so that the shell won't mess around with the value:

```
work:
        echo '$(old) (old)'
```

would print:

```
echo '`find . -mtime +24h -name '$(ts-filename)'` `find . -mtime +24h -name '$(ts-filename)'`'
`find . -mtime +24h -name '$(ts-filename)'` `find . -mtime +24h -name '$(ts-filename)'`
```